# Volume of caps of a polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a polytope in $\mathbb R^d$, blow it up by a factor $\lambda>0$. For a unit vector $u \in \mathbb S^{d-1}$, $\lambda K$ has 2 support hyperplanes $H_1$ and $H_2$ with corresponding outward normal vectors $u$ and $-u$. I only take into account $u$'s such that $H_1$ and $H_2$ have "good" position, that says they are not parallel to any face of $K$, or equivalently, they contain only one vertex of $\lambda K$.

Consider another parallel hyperplane $H_t$ such that the distance between it and $H_1$ is $t$ (of course $t$ is smaller than the width of $\lambda K$ in direction $u$). So $H_1$ and $H_t$ define a cap of $\lambda K$.

My question is: 
Is there a chance that we can estimate the volume of that cap, in terms of $u, \lambda$ and $t$?

The easiest case is when $t$ is smaller than the distance from the nearest vertex of $\lambda K$ to $H_1$, then the volume is $\frac{1}{d}at^d$, where $a$ is a constant depends on $u$.

I mean, in general, it is very hard to compute volume of similarly defined caps of $K$. But if we blow up $K$, some factors can be ignored when $\lambda$ is large enough, so I hope there is a bound on the magnitude of the volume of the cap.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the derivative of the volume of the cap function is a quadratic spline function (I cannot give references at present, but it is a known result). This result is liable to be extended in some way to $\mathbb{R}^d$ for any $d$.

Comment: If $K$ was the ball, the cap volume is exponentially small in the dimension (page 11, here http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf). If your body was symmetric, you could bring it to John's position, and get some estimates from the ball bound. I haven't tried it carefully, though.